# How to embed calculation into COUNTIF function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

My data looks like below:

A  B

1  0

1  0

0  1

0  1

How can I count the number that in the same row column A are greater than column B without adding another column which is the subtracted value between column A and column B?

The output of above example should output 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT((1=1)*(A1:A4>B1:B4))`

Comment: Just found out something similar:
=SUM(IF(B1:B4>A1:A4,1,0))
Please note that this is an array formula. Paste this formula in a cell and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to apply this formula.